# How to return Future<object> and assign it to just object , flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I have a custom class that fetches data from the database, that returns `Future<List<Line>>`, which lies in `line_list.dart` files :

```dart
  Future<List<Line>> fetchingLinesData() async {
    List<Line> lineList = [];
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'main.db');
    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1);
    database.transaction((tnx) async {
      dbRef.child('line').once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) async {
        dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value) async {
          List<Station> inLineStations = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (value["station_$i"] != null) {
              List<Map> stations = await tnx.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Station");
              stations.forEach((s) {
                if (s['stationName'] == value["station_$i"]) {
                  Station stationInstance = Station(
                      key: s['key'],
                      cityName: s['cityName'],
                      stationName: s['stationName'],
                      stationLongitude: s['stationLongitude'],
                      stationLatitude: s['stationLatitude']);
                  inLineStations.add(stationInstance);
                }
              });
            }
          }
          Line lineInstance = Line(
              startStation: value['start_station'],
              endStation: value['end_station'],
              inLineStations: inLineStations,
              notes: value['notes'],
              price: value['price'],
              transportationType: value['transportation_type']);
          lineList.add(lineInstance);
        });
      });
    });
    return lineList;
  }
}
```

and then in my `main.dart` widget, I have this :

```dart
List<Line> allLines = [];
```

I want to do something like this :

```dart
allLines = LinesList().fetchingLinesData();
```

But of course, it gives me an error as am trying to assign `Future<List<Line>>` to `List<Line>`

how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to await for future to complete.

```
allLines = await LinesList().fetchingLinesData();
```

Answer (score 1):

You would  just put the code below in a async function make main async and  make your code

```
allLines = await LinesList().fetchingLinesData();
```